# Why use $\ln x$ and not $\log x$ in most standard intergration formulaes

Tags: integration, logarithms

I wish to understand why we use $\ln x$so much more excessively compared to $\log x$.(log to the base 10)

Taking the following example,
I wish to understand why is it so;

$$ ∫dx/(x^2-a^2 )= \frac{1}{2a} \ln⁡|((x-a)/(x+a))| + c \neq \frac{1}{2a} \log_|(x-a)/(x+a)| + c $$

( *logx* implies logarithm  to the base 10 )

Thank you very much.

Comment: $\ln(x) = \log_{\mathrm{e}}(x)$

Comment: And it often happens to use the notation $\log x$ instead of $\ln x$, in  complex analysis and number theory. [Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalLogarithm.html) they mention $\log x$ as a possible notation for $\log_{10} x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln 10}$

Comment: Your question is predicated on an incorrect assumption. It's an unwritten rule that pure mathematicians use $\log$ for natural logarithm (whereas engineers, physicists, etc. use $\ln$).

Comment: In the context of calculus, the logarithms are implicitly natural, and $\log$ is understood as $\ln$. There is usually no conflict.

Comment: Because you need to carry that constant $\log(b)$ b is your base everywhere and it is extremely annoying.

Comment: Are you aware that $\int \frac 1x~  {\rm d}x = \ln(|x|) + C$ ?  It's not really any deeper than that, every other base would require a conversion constant.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I am sorry, but your dichotomy is not exact at all, at least for my (European) country. Almost all mathematicians, either pure and applied, have switched to notation $ln$. It is in limited circles that $log$ notation is still used (many  engineers for $log_{10}$, theoretical computer science where it often means $log_2$, complex analysis, as it has been remarked).

Comment: IMHO the question is NOT about the notation, but rather about why the natural logarithm is mostly used in calculus instead of any else, for example, why not the decimal one.

Comment: I agree with @A.G. .That is exactly what I am asking.
Thanks

Comment: I think the $\ln$ vs $\log$ debate appeared in the 1970's with the first pocket calculators. Before that, everybody used $\log$ for natural logarithm.

Comment: @JeanMarie If your country is French speaking, I am very surprised by your assertions. To me, the default notation for the default logarithm, unless otherwise specified, is $\log$, hence $\log e=1$ is banal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the standard limit
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1
$$
we know that 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}
$$
with the beautiful unity in the numerator. All other logarithms are proportional to $\ln$
$$
\log_a(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(a)}=\text{const}\cdot\ln(x)
$$
and satisfy
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\log_a(x)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{\ln(a)}}\cdot\frac{1}{x}.
$$
It is less appealing in calculations to take care for this extra constant. It makes the logarithm with the base $e$ *natural* in most calculations in calculus. Moreover, the final conversion from the natural to your particular logarithm of interest is cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Well:

$$\log_e\left(b\right):=\ln\left(b\right)$$

With $e$ is the base of natural logarithm and $e=2.718281828459045...$

Comment: I understand the conversion. My question seeks the reason for the use of natural logarithm rather than the latter (log to the base 10)

Comment: You can use $\log$ but when you use it in the context of $\ln$ you've to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

In calculus, we use the natural logarithm because it's natural!

By this, I mean that any other choice of base would require to introduce a scaling constant in our formula. We can do this, but as a convention mathematicians don't (as it's more work for very little benefit).

An easy example of this isn't with logarithms, but with exponential (which are the inverse of the logarithim), where:

$$\frac{d} {dx} a^x = \ln(a)  a^x$$
This is just how the calculation works out. So, when we choose a base for the exponential, it makes sense to let $a = e$,  as $\ln(e) =1$ so the scaling factor disappears.

This is the heart of the matter. If we choose a non $e$ base, we need to keep track of coefficients more.

Answer (score 0):

Convenience, basically; consider:

- $\frac{d}{dx}\log_{10}x=\frac{1}{\ln 10}\frac{1}{x}$
- $\frac{d}{dx}\ln x=\frac{1}{x}$

Effectively, the base-$e$ logarithm leads to neater, more natural calculations in the framework of differentiation and integration, and is thus favoured in this context. It's similar to how [if you've seen it] we use radians rather than degrees, when using trigonometric functions in calculus - calculations become far more natural through this choice.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to simplify calculations some. The derivative of $log_a(x)$ is $\frac{1}{xln(a)}$. When the base is $a = e$, the natural log term becomes $1$, so we get that the derivative of $ln(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$. In the example you gave (as well as many others), you convert the integrand into something of the form $\frac{du}{u}$ using some form of u-substitution (and possibly partial fractions), so that the antiderivative is the natural logarithm of $u$. You could always choose to use $log_a(x)$ as well, but it carries a constant with it. It's simply standard notation (as well as vaguely nice for calculations) to use natural logarithm instead.